# Can I use PDFBOX with HP UFT 12 vbScript?

Tags: vbscript, pdfbox, hp-uft

Can I use PDFBOX with HP-UFT 12 ?

I know I have seen some topics/questions in which PDFBOX was compatible with QTP, but since currently we are using HP-UFT, I wanted to know if PDFBOX is HP-UFT compatible?

Comment: UFT is just the new name for QTP, any answers about QTP should be the same for UFT.